# f3 / Fat Free Framework: why does the SQL-Mapper select function return all columns from a table?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Imagine a MySQL table with two columns, col1 and col2, queried by f3's SQL-Mapper like this:

```
$rows = $mapper->find();
$rows = $mapper->select('col1');
```

When using *find* both columns are queried and returned and one can access them like this:

```
... = $rows[0]->col1;
... = $rows[0]->col2;
```

When using *select* calling *$rows[0]->col2* will return null, because *col2* was not included in the string argument of the *select* method, which is fine.

Now when doing a var_dump I noticed that the *select* method returns all columns! Why is this?

I imagined the purpose of the *select* method would be to save resources on the database server by only querying for the specified columns. So what is the purpose of the [SQL-Mapper: select](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/sql-mapper#select) method if it returns the full set of columns – we have the *find* method for that, don't we?

Comment: Looks like a bug according to https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/databases#SometimesItJustAin'tEnough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the Fat-Free SQL mapper is to automatically *map* table columns to PHP object properties. This is done at instantiation time in `DB\SQL\Mapper::__construct`.

So when you call `$mapper->find()` or `$mapper->select()`, the instantiation has already been performed and table columns have already been mapped to the `$mapper` object.

This explains the results of your `var_dump` command.

Now you can adjust the list of columns actually mapped, but that has to be done at instantiation:

```
// map all columns
$mapper = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'table_name');

// only map col1 & col2 columns
$mapper = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'table_name','col1,col2');
```

Concerning the `select()` method, I'm wondering why this method has been made public. It is used internally by `find()`, but is not very handy to use on its own, considering that all the specified fields have to match declared columns at instantiation and that computed columns should be both aliased AND declared. See:

```
$mapper = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'table_name','col1,col2');

// ex.1: column not declared
$results = $mapper->select('*');
echo $results[0]->col3; // undefined field col3

// ex.2a: computed column not aliased
$results = $mapper->select('SUM(col1)');
echo $results[0]->{'SUM(col1)'}; // undefined field SUM(col1)

// ex.2b: computed column aliased but not declared
$results = $mapper->select('SUM(col1) AS sum1');
echo $results[0]->sum1; // undefined field sum1

// ex.2c: computed column declared but not aliased
$mapper->sum1 = 'SUM(col1)';
$results = $mapper->select('SUM(col1)');
echo $results[0]->sum1; // empty

// ex.2d: computed column aliased and declared
$mapper->sum1 = 'SUM(col1)';
$results = $mapper->select('SUM(col1) AS sum1');
echo $results[0]->sum1; // OK!
```

As you can see, the usage of this method is very strict. I wouldn't advise to use it, unless you really know what you're doing. Use `find()` instead.